# Wrong return of UIImageView.isAnimating?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a Problem with using the `isAnimating` function.

I have got an UIImageView called imgBecher.
In the `viewDidLoad` function I play a small Animation:

```
    imgBecher.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.11.png"];
    AniArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.1.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.2.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.3.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.4.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.5.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.6.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.7.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.8.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.9.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"diceholderAni.10.png"],
                nil];
    imgBecher.animationImages = AniArray;
    [imgBecher setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    imgBecher.animationDuration = 1;
    [imgBecher startAnimating];
```

Everything fine so far.
Now I call a Loop with:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)gameLoop {
    NSLog(@"%i",imgBecher.isAnimating);
}
```

Now gameLoop fires 1 all over the time, not seeing that the animation is over.

BUT
as soon as I touch the screen anywhere, it fires 0, just as it should be.

I need this later on, where I have 4 animations, which should be played right after another without any user actions.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use `userInteractionEnabled` property:

`imgBecher.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` or `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`